# How can I highlight my code?

Tags: wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I use a wordpress blog (free hosting). This is my personal blog for mathematics and programming post. I try in many ways to post my C++ codes using syntax highlighter, but unable to do so. How can I highlight my C/C++/java codes in my blog post? Help me please.

Comment: I have [this plugin](https://github.com/brasofilo/snippets-shortcode) for that.

Answer (score 0):

Look here - here is an [article](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) about highlighting in Wordpress.org hosting.

In the bottom of article, at the credits section you can find link for this plugin.
I'll dublicate it [here](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) for more convenience.

Comment: I had use this code format before:
[code language="css"]
your code here
[/code]
but the codes had not highlighted. I think the cause is, I use a free hosting. But I saw some free hosting site(e.g. http://zobayer2009.wordpress.com/code/#template) who are using code highlighter but I don't know how do they do that.